# What will be equivalent of following code in es5?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

What will be equivalent of following code in es5?

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = { ...this.props };
}
```

Comment: `this.state = Object.assign({}, this.props)`

Comment: I think Object.assign still counts as es6. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.assign. With es5 you just have to copy everything over or use helpers in underscore or lodash

Comment: You could always let Babel compile it to ES5 code and see what it does.

Comment: @chenkehxx: it works, thanks! Also, how would I write this one in es5? `this.state = { editFlag : false, ...this.props }`

Comment: @BhushanLodha it should be `this.state = Object.assign({editFlag: false}, this.props)`, or maybe `this.state=_.extend({editFlag: false}, this.props)` is easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code would look something like this without using any >= ES6 syntax.

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  // super(props)
  React.Component.call(this, props);

  // this.state = { ...this.props };
  this.state = Object.assign({}, props);
}
```

Babel's site [has a repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/) which you can use to see exactly what the compiled code will look like.

In this case [it's quite complex](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0&code=class%20A%20extends%20B%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor(props)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20super(props)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20this.state%20%3D%20%7B%20...this.props%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&playground=false) because it's mostly wrapped up in the class utilities that Babel uses to polyfill ES6 classes for ES5.

---

The second example of `this.state = { editFlag : false, ...this.props }` would be similar.

```
this.state = Object.assign({}, editFlag: false, this.props);
```